# How to connect hornetq on AWS VPC from another vm on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, hornetq, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have 2 VMs on AWS. On the first VM I have hornet and application that send messages to hornet. On another VM I have application that is a consumer of hornet.
The consumer fails to pull messages from hornet, and I can't understand why. Hornetq is running, I opened to ports to any IP.
I tried to connect hornet with jconsole (on my local computer) and failed, so I can't see if the hornet has any consumers/ suppliers.

I've tried to change 'bind' configurations to 0.0.0.0 but when I restarted hornet they were automatically changed to what I have as server IP in config.properties.

Any suggestions what might be the problem that I failed to connect my application to the hornetq?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are the things you need to check for the connectivity between VMs in VPC.

1. The Security- Group of the instance has both Ingress-Egress Configuration settings unlike the traditional EC2 Security Group [ now Classic EC2 ]. Check the Egress from your Consumer and ingress to the Server
2. If the instances are in different Subnets you need to check for the ACL as well; however the default setting would be allow.
3. Check if the iptables / OS level firewall which are blocking.

With respect to the connectivity failed from your local machine to Hornetq - you need to place the Instance in Public sub and configure the Instance's SG accordingly; only the app / VM would accessible to public internet

I have assumed that both the instances are in the Same VPC. However the title of the post sounds slightly misleading - if it is 2 different VPCs altogether, then new concept of VPC Peering also comes in